# Add line after matching a pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed, echo

I have a file say **test** with following values

```
Linux
Solaris
Fedora
Ubuntu
AIX
HPUX
```

How to add a line with system hostname after the line matching AIX? If I do

```
echo `hostname` >> test
```

system hostname comes at the last after HPUX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed "s/^AIX$/& $(hostname)/" file
```

If the line could **contain** `AIX`:

```
sed "s/AIX.*/& $(hostname)/" file
```

**Edit:**

To append the hostname after the matching line, try the `a`(append) command:

```
sed "/^AIX$/a $(hostname)" file
```

Comment: Sorry what i meant was to append to the next line after AIX

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you.

```
 awk -v host=$(hostname) '$0 == "AIX"{print $0 RS host;next} 1'  Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** Adding 1 more solution too here.

```
awk -v host=$(hostname) '{printf("%s%s\n",$0,$0=="AIX"?RS host:"")}'
```

Comment: Sorry what i meant was to append to the next line after AIX

Comment: @gosatriani, changed the code now, please check and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Good portable solution not limited to sed version! (e.g. works also on mac)

Comment: @al-ash, your welcome cheers and happy learning

Comment: Thx! Actually, I just realized that your awk script is not matching a line with "AIX" pattern but line which is identical "AIX". Per the title of this thread, it might be useful to append to your answer that "~" instead of "==" comparator could be used here.

Comment: @al-ash, since answer is old one I am not editing it right now, as per your suggestion  I am adding it here for future user's reference `awk -v host=$(hostname) '{printf("%s%s\n",$0,$0~/^AIX$/?RS host:"")}'` cheers.