# Insert new text at every X line using vi editor

Tags: vim, yaml, vi

I currently have a yaml file (this file is large and follows the same format below):

```
- created_at: 2021-01-18 15:11:44
  created_by: joe
  hostname: sfo
  ip: 1.1.1.1
  opersys: tmsh
  platform: f5
  role: lb
  type: loadbalancer
- created_at: 2021-01-18 15:11:44
  created_by: joe
  hostname: sjc
  ip: 2.2.2.2
  opersys: tmsh
  platform: f5
  role: lb
  type: loadbalancer
```

I want to insert a new text (serial_num: xxxxx) at every 8th line so it looks like this:

```
- created_at: 2021-01-18 15:11:44
  created_by: joe
  hostname: sfo
  ip: 1.1.1.1
  opersys: tmsh
  platform: f5
  role: lb
  type: loadbalancer
  serial_num: xxxxx
- created_at: 2021-01-18 15:11:44
  created_by: joe
  hostname: sjc
  ip: 2.2.2.2
  opersys: tmsh
  platform: f5
  role: lb
  type: loadbalancer
  serial_num: xxxxx
```

Comment: Do you really need "at every 8th line", or can we do after each `type:` line? Are you also open to Awk solutions?

Comment: Yup, after 'type:' is just fine. I'm opened to awk solutions as well... Whatever that can provide the same results. Can you also show a solution for before 'type:' as well? Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add line after matching a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48002485/add-line-after-matching-a-pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure Vim, with `:help :global` and `:help :put`:

```
" after every line matching 'type:'
:g/type:/put='  serial_num: xxxxx'

" before every line matching 'type:'
:g/type:/put!='  serial_num: xxxxx'
```

Pure Vim, with `:help :global` and `:help :normal`:

```
" after every line matching 'type:'
:g/type:/normal oserial_num: xxxxx

" before every line matching 'type:'
:g/type:/normal Oserial_num: xxxxx
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU Sed

```sh
sed '/type: /a\  serial_num: xxxxx' your_file
```

Comment: Thanks @Enlico. How do I insert it before 'type:'?

Comment: @superloopnetworks use `i` instead of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

A regex based solution is:

```
:%s/\(\(^.*\n\)\{8}\)/\1  serial_num: xxxxx\r/g
```

Where `^.*\n` match a single whole line till the return character `\n`, then `\{8}` repeats the selection 8 times, `\(...\)` encapsulate the final group.